# Android SQL: Check if Record in Database Exists

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to query my database based on a specific id.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM mash WHERE recipe_id = '" + id + "'";
Cursor data = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

If this is the first time the activity has been run, the table WILL exist along with the id column, but there will not be a record with the specific id. How can I check if that specific record exists and if it does not, add it? I have found lots of into regarding checking if a specific column exists, but nothing about checking if a specific record exists.

So far I have tried getting the id column index and checking to see if it returns -1, but it actually is returning 1 for some reason. What can I use in an if statement to verify that the id column has not yet been created?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // record exists
} else {
    // record not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Code is:

```
public void addContact(String a, String b, String c, String d, SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        //cursor is use to check if data is availble then show row is exist if not then execute insert query.
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE    email=? ", new String[]{b});

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            value=false;
            Toast.makeText(context,"Email alreay exist please enter anothe email id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(Database_Handler.NAME, a); // Contact Name
            values.put(Database_Handler.EMAIL, b);
            values.put(Database_Handler.PASSWORD, c);
            values.put(Database_Handler.NUMBER, d);

            db.insert(Database_Handler.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
            Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", "One row is insert");

            Toast.makeText(context,"Data insert Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close();
            value=true;

        }
    }
```