# compare sqlite with string

Tags: android, sql

I saved Data in my SQL databank.

Now I want to compare this saved data, with a string

Something like this:

```
String example = "house";
```

Now I want to check, if "house" is already in the databank, with a if clause

something like this

```
if ( example == [SQL Data] ) {
}
else {
}
```

Now, how can I accomplish this ?

Comment: do you have just a single column or more than one column?

Comment: So this seems more like a sql issue. Take a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634984/insert-if-not-exists-else-update , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418898/sqlite-upsert-not-insert-or-replace

Comment: Start with [SQLiteDatabase.html#query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) or one of its variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing my reply to Sharath's comment as an answer, as the code will be messed up in a comment:

Not saying your reply is wrong, but it's really inefficient to select everything from the table and iterate over it outside the database and it shouldn't be suggested as an answer to the question, because it's a bad habbit to do like that in general.

The way I usually do it, if I want to see if some record is present in the database, I do like this. Not gonna argue about using do-while over a normal while-loop, because that's about different preferences ;)

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name=" + the_example_string_to_find;              
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        // Do whatever you like with the result.
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer
sadly i get a nullpointerexception here:  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery

Comment: the problem is, im on a broadcastreceiver

Comment: How do you create the database?

Comment: **Do not append strings to the query!** Instead use the `query` methods like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919686/compare-sqlite-with-string/43574206#43574206) and add the string without quotation to the `selection_args`.

Comment: @Burdui the only change between my answer and the other answer is the quotations. I don't understand what your point is.

Comment: @Darwind Directly appending strings to the query opens a path for SQL injecetion if the string originates from userinput.

Comment: @Burdui yes you&#39;re right, but the other answer doesn&#39;t help on that either. You should probably go with `Sqlite#compileStatement` of you wanna be on the safe side or just use Room now a days.
compileStatement produces prepared statement which are precompiled before usage.

Comment: @Darwind The CompiledStatement objects arne ["used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times"](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement). Every statement gets precompiled but __the selection_args should bei used__. Apparently this is also true for the rawQuery method.

Answer (score 10):

Do something like

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column = '" + example + "'";
Cursor data = database.rawQuery(sql, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
// record exists
} else {
// record not found
}
```

stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886189/android-sql-check-if-record-in-database-exists)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Getting Specific  Record by name. 
// in DB handler class make this function call it by sending search criteria. 
    Records getRecord(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_Auth_Name, KEY_B_PRICE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{name}, null, null, null,null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        Records Records = new Records(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));
// return book
        return Records;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to first fetch all the data from the database and next check the data with what you obtained from the database.

Have a look at the link [sample database example](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html)

suppose you got a cursor object from the database

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT yourColumnName FROM "+TABLE_NAME, null);
if(!cursor.moveToFirst()){

 }
 else{

do {
if(cursor.getString(0).equals(example)) 
 //do something which you want and break
 break;
 } while (cursor.moveToNext());

 }
```

Comment: Performancewise your approach is completely wrong. Your raw query should look like this instead: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE row_name = the_example_string.
Don't just select everything in the database and compare it in the programming language when the database can do it much more efficiently.
Also the Android SQLite DB class has a method called getCount(), where you can get the number of rows returned, when doing a select.

Comment: yes you are right but he didnt mention whether he need the data of some particular value so that we can use a where clause.
His information just was to search whether the string is present in the database or not for which we need to get the whole data from the database. Is my approach wrong ? If so can you suggest any other way  please